# How to time an animation in android

Tags: android, android-animation, loader

I am animating a loader on start up. How can I work around it so that instead of using ontouch listener to stop the timer, I use a time of say like 3 seconds? Here is my code:

```
private void showdiag() {
    loader = findViewById(R.id.loader);
    logo= loader.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    logo.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rotate));
    loader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });




}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `View.postDelayed()` to run some action after a set delay:

```
private void showdiag() {
    loader = findViewById(R.id.loader);
    logo = loader.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    logo.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate));

    loader.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 logo.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
  @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

  }

  @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
   loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }

  @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this makes it run infinitely. I want to set the time so that it runs for 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try following code.  

     logo.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
          @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

          }

          @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
           loader.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }, 3000);
          }

          @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

          }
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately @namezhouyu my reputation does not allow me to do that yer.